# How do I get m2eclipse to recognize $M2_OPTS?

Tags: maven-2, m2eclipse

It appears m2eclipse is not recognizing my $M2_OPTS variable.

I can run the same build outside of eclipse fine (with cranked up heapsize):

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 51 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Nov 10 00:00:02 EST 2009
[INFO] Final Memory: 72M/187M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But when I run this with m2eclipse I always run out of memory:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Java heap space
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    ...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1 minute 27 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Nov 09 23:56:32 EST 2009
[INFO] Final Memory: 43M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any ideas?

*SOLUTION* : Add the mem args to the Installed JREs tab of the Java preferences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently an issue about this, see [MNGECLIPSE-1182](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE-1182?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel), and a workaround:

> ... you can specify default JVM arguments in Window / Preferences / Java / Installed JREs.

But actually, this comment is confusing me:

> [ It appears as though the current
>   m2eclipse plugin still honors the
>   `M2_OPTS` environment variable when
>   using an external maven installation.
>
> So I just defined both of them:
>   `MAVEN_OPTS` for running `mvn` from
>   command prompts and `M2_OPTS` for
>   running maven from m2eclipse. E.g. set
>   `M2_OPTS=-Xmx256M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M`
>
> I'm using Maven 2.1.0 and Maven
>   Integration for Eclipse version
>   0.9.9.200907071528 with Eclipse Galileo. ]

Comment: Hmmm.  Good point.  I looked again, and I had defined $MAVEN_OPTS, not $M2_OPTS.

After I added a $M2_OPTS, things seem to work out the same way.  So I'm equally as baffled.  I cleared the Maven settings and everything and still no dice.

Comment: I cranked the mem args on the installed VM and everything worked.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I followed this same answer to specify other MAVEN_OPTS arguments (keystore and truststore for my HTTPS Artifactory server) and it fixed a similar issue where JARs were not being downloaded from Artifactory because Eclipse was not using MAVEN_OPTS to communicate with Artifactory.