# maven pom how to add a java agent argument

Tags: java, maven, jvm, javac

I am running my project from eclipse and I simply add a JVM argument like this:

```
-javaagent:path to my ho hw ho folder/openjpa-2.3.0.jar
```

now i am running my code from the server ,and I do have the pom there, i would like to ask you if it is possible to add that javaagent from the pom

#### What i have tried

:
i added a `<jvmSettings>` in the pom, so basically i did this:

```
    <jvmSettings>
    <systemProperties>
 <systemProperty>javaagent=path to my ho hw ho folder/openjpa-2.3.0.jar</systemProperty>
    </systemProperties>
    </jvmSettings>
```

my question is: is that correct? do i need to add the `-` before `javaagent`?

Comment: have you tried the solution here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777909/specify-javaagent-argument-with-maven-exec-plugin

Answer (score -2):

You could use environment variable to pass in Java argument `-javaagent` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1705858/260990)